# C# How to embed an existing browser inside the main display window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have just started working on an application that has been written in C#. The bulk of the application is displayed in a window created by the application (desgined in XAML- so the class is `MainWindow.xaml.cs`).

I want to add the functionality of displaying a particular website inside the application, and allowing the user to interact with that website.

A browser has already been created in the application, and it is fully functional; however, when the user clicks the button to display the required website, a new application window is opened as a 'dedicated' browser to show that website. What I want to do, is take the browser that is currently being opened in a separate window, and embed that inside the main window of the application, rather than opening a second window.

The 'MainWindow', where I want to display the browser, is defined with the line:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{
```

and the browser, that is currently being opened in a separate window, is defined with the line:

```
partial class RBrowser : Form{
```

The button that opens the browser when clicked, is calling the function:

```
private void testFunction3(object sender, EventArgs e){
    mBrowser.Show();
    mBrowser.goPage("www.google.com");
}
```

I tried to add `RBrowser` to `MainWindow` by doing the following:

```
System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();

            rBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(rBrowser);

            groupBox1.Text = "RIVIAM";
            groupBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            groupBox1.Enabled = true;

            //this.Add(groupBox1);
            //mBrowser.Dock();

            rBrowser.Show();
            rBrowser.goPage("https://web.riviam.com/");
```

This code is called from a method written in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` when the user clicks a button on the main window of the application. `rBrowser` is an instance of `RBrowser`.

How can I get this function to show the web browser `rBrowser` inside the `MainWindow`, rather than in a new window?

At the moment, when I run this, and click the button on the GUI to open the browser, I get the following exceptions:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Top-level control cannot be added to a control.

and these highlight the line:

```
groupBox1.Controls.add(rBrowser);
```

Comment: Why are you using `Form` in wpf? Ther'es a `WebBrowser` control and `Frame` control for showing web pages.

Comment: @EmperorAiman The browser control in WPF is actually a WinForms control.

Comment: I am working with code that someone else wrote some time ago- trying to get what they had done working. The aim is to give the user access only to a particular website, not the full internet- so when the browser loads, it will automatically load that website, and the navigation tools will only allow them to browse through the history of their session. Since they do not have access to an address bar, they will not be able to navigate outside of the website on which the form/ browser loads.

Comment: I would re-write the existing code by embedding a browser like <WebBrowser x:Name="wbMain" Margin="30"> </WebBrowser> in your XAML file.

Comment: it's possibe to host winforms controls in wpf, there are lots of tutorials. But I haven't checked it because I can do everything in WPF>

Comment: I can add a simple browser to the `MainWindow`, however, the features of the built in `WebBrowser` class do not seem to support JavaScript- the site that I need to give the user access to relies heavily on JS...

Comment: Which is why I am using this `RBrowser` class, which was designed and built by the last person working on this software for my web browser